# How to serve static files with express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to serve static files with express.js.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.listen(8888, () => console.log('listening on port 8888!'))
```

but I'm getting error:  Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8888/static/css/main.5a7f7b3b.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: does your css file starts with a comment ?

Comment: @HamzaFatmi No it does not

Comment: Did you actually check what you got back from the css request? I'm guessing your path is wrong somehow, and the server is sending back a  404 or something else with html. Check that you actually have a path `public/static/css` in your project dir, and you can also use something like `require('path').join(__dirname, 'public')` to make sure the path works even when not run in project root.

Answer (score 0):

I´m probably late, but I just found out the answer and could not find it anywhere else, so I will post it:

The problem with your code is, that it will serve the index.html correctly, but when it loads the .css files, which are linked in the .html file, the application will respond by sending the .html file again. Your browser is expecting to get a .css file but actually gets a .html file, which is causing the error.

This will fix it:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path');
const app = express()
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./path/To/Your/Dir"));
}); 
app.listen(8888, () => console.log('listening on port 8888!'))
```